# Email Tracking is shown in wrong View

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've set up e-mail tracking following this manual:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email

My tracking URL is valid and seems to work since it shows up in Google Analytics (Realtime->Events), but it is showing up in the wrong view.

My Google Analytics account has an 'account' with 12 'properties' which has 3 'views'. The tracked events only show up in the first view listed (which I use for a subdomain), my 'main' view for the root domain is the second one listed and the events are not tracked in this view.

I noticed these views have a 'view ID', but I can not find a parameter in the Measurement Protocol manual that allows me to set it:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters

How can I switch the view in which my email tracking events are stored? Or perhaps enable the tracking in my other views as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is collected on the property level, that's why there is no parameter for the measurement protocol to set the view. Views merely filter and display the data from the property.

So the events should show up by default, if not you have probably some filter that excludes the data from those particular views (e.g. something like a hostname filter, since your measurement protocol calls won't have a hostname set).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my stupidity. I was indeed filtering out my own IP!